# Python remote debuging with PyCharm and ptvsd

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a virtual machine running a python process and I want to debug it from my host.
My virtual machine ip is 192.168.10.20.
As per the instructions I set up my launch.json as

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "localRoot": "/Users/wrkspace",
        "remoteRoot": "/home/wrkspace",
        "port": 3000,
        "secret": "my_secret",
        "host": "192.168.10.20"
    },
```

I have two files,one on my host machine and on my vm called test.py which is a helloworld asking for a user input
My host machine has this at the top of the file

```
ptvsd.enable_attach("my_secret", address = ('192.168.10.20'3000))

# Enable the line of source code below only if you want the application 
to wait until the debugger has attached to it
#ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

While on my vm, where I want to debug

```
ptvsd.enable_attach("my_secret", address = ('192.168.10.20'3000))

# Enable the line of source code below only if you want the application 
to wait until the debugger has attached to it
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

Once I run my attached debugger and then I kick of the test on my vm by going python test.py. It looks like it does something but then fails with

There was an error in starting the debug server. 
Error="code":"ENETUNREACH","errno":"ENETUNREACH","syscall":"connect","address":"192.168.10.20","port":3000}

There was an error in starting the debug server. Error = {"code":"ENETUNREACH","errno":"ENETUNREACH","syscall":"connect","address":"192.168.10.20","port":3000}

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

A few steps to trouble shoot these:

> 1) test the debug port to make sure it is open using "nc -zv test.com 30302"
>
> 2) make sure your webserver is not reloading the app after debugger was connected to it. this is the option for flask: " use_reloader=False"